# pg-copy-stream crashes when using the copy postgres command in lambda

Tags: postgresql, aws-lambda, postgresql-copy

I am trying to write a lambda which will be used to get data from PostgreSQL using a query.
I am using pg-copy-stream's 'to' function to convert my query into a stream and passing it to client.query().

When I run tests locally they crash saying that "could not send data to client broken pipe" (found this in my PostgreSQL table log).

My connection to PostgreSQL client also terminates when this line is executed.

I have already done an exhaustive research but am unable to figure out why this is happening.

I have considered other options as well but pg-copy-stream library should work as expected if I am following the documentation right.

Here is the code where the connection terminates:

```
const createReadableStream = (pgClient: Client): CopyToStreamQuery => { 
const exportQuery = "copy (select * from schema.view as scv where scv.number = 200) to stdout with (format csv, delimiter ',', quote '\"', header);";
return pgClient.query(copyTo(exportQuery));
};
```

Comment: what error you get exactly? timeout or something else? did you check lambda timeout limits ?

Comment: I have not deployed the lambda yet. I am running locally.
When I run test on the lambda using jest it fails prematurely saying connection to client terminated. When I check postgres log it shows "could not send data to client broken pipe".

I have a funtion called s3Upload which I am stubbing in my test and I want my tests to reach there, But the test fails before it reaches that fucntion. It fails on this line pgClient.query(copyTo(exportQuery)). Here he connection is terminated prematurely.

Comment: There is a [good explanation about what that broken pipe means](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/110525). So this may happen from client anti virus blocking some data pipes or network connections, or there is a firewall between client and server that firewall is breaking the connection. These are the options comes to my mind.